# AWS API Gateway to remove specific named header(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am rather new to AWS API Gateway, and I'm trying to find out the way to pass-through a REST request from our server to another venders server using API Gateway.
Because the proxied target server belongs to other company, we want to authenticate by authentication header other than 'X-API-KEY' (ex. 'X-MY-API-KEY') and simply remove the header 'X-MY-API-KEY' when passing the request to the proxied server.
I read AWS document, but sadly I couldn't find the way to remove a header with specific name.

I tried API-KEY authentication, but it seems the authentication header name is fixed to 'X-API-KEY' which we don't want to use because it may conflict with proxied service authentication headers.

The questions are...

A) Is it possible to remove a header with specific name on API-Gateway pass-through?

A-i) If it is possible, how can I setup the setting?

B) If I can change the header name of 'X-API-KEY' to arbitral name when using API-KEY authentication, that is perfect. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you use lambda proxy integration? Then your lambda could proxy the other company's server and adjust or pass-through headers as desired.

Comment: Did you verify whether API Gateway doesn't, perhaps, just automatically remove X-API-Key from the proxied request?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.
I checked that X-API-KEY is automatically removed, so if the header name 'X-API-KEY' could be changed to something else like mentioned above is the perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, using lambda integration is one option, still we need to work on implementing re-building request to proxy servers, which is essential part we want to abbreviate if we use API Gateway. One another possible option I am studying is using Lambda authorizer, which takes header for authorization token.

Comment: Lambda authorizer worked.